# UnboundLocalError for local variable 'value' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

The code below can be run, but it always results in the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'value' referenced before assignment` when one attempts to type. I've been on many sites, but can't seem to apply the solutions I get to my specific situation:

```
def letterbreak(luv):
    setluv=list(str(luv))
    for x in setluv:
        if x=='a':
            value=int(1)
        if x=='b':
            value=int(2)
        if x=='c':
            value=int(3)
        if x=='d':
            value=int(4)
        if x=='e':
            value=int(5)
        if x=='f':
            value=int(6)
        .......
        .......
        .......
        .......

        if x=='y':
            value=int(25)
        if x=='z':
            value=int(26)
        print(str(value))
    return

letterbreak(input())
```

Please let me know if there is something wrong with the conditions.

Comment: You might want to dive into the topic of dictionaries in Python, or even better: the [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function.

Answer (score 3):

You don't define `value` if no conditions execute. So, what value must be printed if `x == '1'`?

The solution is to define a default value before `if`:

```
for x in setluv:
    value = -1

    if x=='a':
        value=int(1)
    # ... etc

    print(str(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

On a side note (too long for comment), your code could be simplified quite a bit. For instance, you could be using a look up table as in:

```
import string
tmp = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
lookup = dict(zip(tmp, range(1, len(tmp)+1)))

def letterbreak(luv):
    setluv=list(str(luv))
    for x in setluv:
        print(str(lookup.get(x, "Value not defined")))
    return
```

Comment: Thanks; I'm new to coding and teaching myself it through online sources. Thanks for the support

Comment: No worries. Been there myself!